# Problems generating data from a form with mutiple submit buttons, submitted with the python requests module

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I use the following website as part of my work:

http://octopus.cbr.su.se/

and would like to be able to use it from a script.

I'm using the requests (python-requests.org) module and am trying the following code:

```
import requests
octopus_url = "http://octopus.cbr.su.se/"
data = { 'value' : 'Submit OCTOPUS', 'name' : 'do',  'sequence' : 'QPRRKLCILHRNPGRCYDKIPAFYYNQKKKQCERFDWSGCGGNSNRFKTIEECRRTCIG' }
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post( octopus_url, data=data )
print r.text
```

The general approach seems to work on other websites, but on this one no matter what I do, the post data seems to be ignored and I just get the page displayed as if I'd just visited it.

Is there anything obvious I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you compared what is posted with what your *browser* posts when you visit that site? Web servers can do whatever the hell they please, based on *every* byte of data you send them. If `requests` sends different data from what your browser sends, then you can expect different behaviour.

Comment: In other words, this is not a `requests` problem, but a problem with a *very specific website*. That makes this question way Too Localized I am afraid, see the [faq#close].

Comment: I thought it might be something specific to do with the way the POST was being handled on the sever, but jimhark's answer works for me so it looks like I was just sending the wrong data in the POST. I guess it is just a local misunderstanding then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the site [makes the code available for download](http://octopus.cbr.su.se/index.php?about=download). Would it be possible for you to run it locally?

To answer your question, the HTML for the submit button is:

```
<input type="submit" name="do" value="Submit OCTOPUS">
```

So where you have:

```
'value' : 'Submit OCTOPUS', 
'name' : 'do',
```

You need:

```
'do' : 'Submit OCTOPUS'
```

With the rest of your code you get:

```
import requests

octopus_url = "http://octopus.cbr.su.se/"

data = {
    'do' : 'Submit OCTOPUS',
    'sequence' : 'QPRRKLCILHRNPGRCYDKIPAFYYNQKKKQCERFDWSGCGGNSNRFKTIEECRRTCIG'
}

s = requests.Session()
r = s.post( octopus_url, data=data )
print r.text
```

Which I tested and is working for me.

Comment: The download and build look fairly heavyweight and I was just after something really lightweight. However, your suggestion works perfectly for me, so many thanks for pointing out where I was going wrong.

Comment: Updated answer to also remove `'value' : 'Submit OCTOPUS'`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Glad this worked for you. You probably would have gotten several quick answers had you posted the form's HTML with your question (but then I would have been too late to help). Also more users will read your code if you format it for readability. Some of the lines of code you posted were long. I broke up your data assignment line in my answer. The formatting made the problem stand out better (at least it helped me).

Comment: Many thanks for the tips - all very useful and definitely things I'll bear in mind for next time.